# Symfony2 error : Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names:

Tags: symfony

I'm working on Symfony2 and i updated my project with `composer.phar update`

Now, when i check my site with `app_dev.php` i always have this error :

```
Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: Blu\ProjectBun
  dle\Entity\AccountRepository vs Blu\ProjectBundle\Entity\AccountRepos
  itory
```

It's the same when i clear the dev cache, manually or not. I have nothing special in AccountRepository.php..

Any ideas ?

Edit : I already tried to add `if ($name !== $class && 0 === strcasecmp($name, $class)) {` in `DebugClassLoader.php` and no effect

Comment: looks like inside the file its written small e.g -> class accountRepository {}

Comment: I have nothing special in this file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intent to var_dump($name) and var_dump($class) and strcasecmp($name, $class) to see why you enter in the condition.

Answer (score 3):

though the answer was a typo in the class namespace, this errors occurs also if your entity is defined via xml, i.e. User.orm.xml, and you accidentally name the file lower-case, this will drive nuts the xml loader

1. create FooNamespace\BarBundle\Resources\config\User.orm.xml
2. create FooNamespace\BarBundle\Entity\User.php (class User { ... })

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and after trying all the solutions I found, no one of them worked for me. I am working with Symfony 2.8, Doctrine ORM and Sonata Admin Bundle and this exception appeared when I added an admin class (for a class related with the class showed in the exception message) and I tried to open it.

My mistake was I wrote the name of the database tables in lowercase in Doctrine annotations in the class related, check if you have it in uppercase:

```
ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Symfony2 :

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/8e9cc35

It has been merged in 2.5 but not tagged yet ([source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11030))

To check if this is really the case for you, you might want to try modifying the `src/Symfony/Component/Debug/DebugClassLoader.php` file manually :

```
// Line 178
if ($name !== $class && 0 === strcasecmp($name, $class)) {
```

... and check if you still have the problem after clearing your cache

Comment: I have already try this thing, and i always have this error ;)

Comment: In your error, it doesn't say "`in file_XX at line YY`" to try to track down the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Please Add this if condition in DebugClassLoader.php File at line 177

```
    if ($name === $class) {
        if ($name !== $class && 0 === strcasecmp($name, $class)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: %s vs %s', $class, $name));
        } 
    }
```

It will solve your problem

Location: `root\Projectname\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your controller name first word is lowercase in your routing.yml

```
usr_teacher_new:
path:     /new
defaults: { _controller: CoreUserBundle:teacher:newteacher }
```

like teacher..

will be **T**eacher