# Error while generating doctrine entities with FOSUser Bundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUser bundle and everything went ok until I tried to create the database entities, I get this error:

It has nothing to do with the bug in Symfony 2.5, I'm using version 2.7

```
Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: App\UserBundle\Entity\user vs App\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

This is my config file for fos:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

My classes and namespaces they seem to have the right caps, I don't know why this is happening. I tried to clear the cache, no errors but didn't work.

The user class is App/UserBundle/Entity/User.php, here's the content:

```
<?php
namespace App\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the file name of the User class?

Comment: Hi, I added that info in the question :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 error : Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268366/symfony2-error-case-mismatch-between-loaded-and-declared-class-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I was using yaml for the entity definition and the filename was user.orm.yml instead of User.orm.yml.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you amend your User entity to appear as below (replacing `user_table` with intended table name)?

```
namespace App\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_table")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```