# Symfony 3 error : Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names

Tags: php, symfony, mismatch

i've just got this error

> **Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\post vs MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\Post**

i'm using two controllers to do a specific operation of delete and getting back to the old page

here is my button's code

```
<a href="{{ path('DeleteComment',{'idc':comment.id}) }}"></a>
                                <a href="{{ path('DeleteComment',{'idc':comment.id}) }}"> <i
                                            class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</a>
```

here is my routing's code :

```
get_view_post:
path:     /blog/get/one/post/{id}/
defaults: { _controller: "MyAppBlogBundle:Blog:getpost" }
DeleteComment:
path:     /blog/post/comment/delete/{idc}/
defaults: { _controller: "MyAppBlogBundle:Blog:DeleteComment" }
```

here is my controllers code :

```
public function DeleteCommentAction($idc)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $comment = $em->getRepository('MyAppUserBundle:PostComment')->find($idc);
    $idPost =$comment->getIdPost();


    $em->remove($comment);
    $em->flush();


    return $this->redirectToRoute("get_view_post", array('id' => $idPost));
}


 public function getpostAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $idu = $user->getId();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $post = $em->getRepository('MyAppUserBundle:Post')->find($id);
    $idPost=$post->getId();
    $comment = $em1->getRepository('MyAppUserBundle:PostComment')->findBy(array('idPost' => $idPost));
    return $this->render('MyAppBlogBundle::afficherPostAvecComment.html.twig', array('posts' => $post,'comments'=>$comment,'idu'=>$idu));

}
```

i'm declaring my entities like this :

```
use MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\Post;
use MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\PostComment;
```

**Here is my Entity**

```
namespace MyApp\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 */
class Post
{


/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
 */
private $titre;
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="contenu", type="string", length=250, nullable=false)
 */
private $contenu;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateajout", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateajout ;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_utilisateur",referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $idUser;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="nbLike", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $nbLike =0;
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="nbDislike", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $nbDislike=0;
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="nbSignal", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $nbSignal=0;
```

Comment: The err message is about post vs Post.  Nothing to do with your controllers.  If I had to guess, given your somewhat imaginative naming convention, you have class post.  Or maybe a typo in your PostComment relation.  And of course, make sure your cache is cleared if you have been editing the entity stuff.

Comment: i've changed every array's name to "p" and still getting the same problem, i can show you other parts of my code if you want to check it

Comment: Change the code in your question to show the entity Post, there should be the problem.

Comment: i posted it , u can have a look

Comment: And show your post relation inside of the PostComment entity.  Better yet, just search for 'post' and see what pops up.

Comment: Believe it of nott i did some ridiculous changes and it worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i did some changes in my code, as i see My IDE couldn't differentiate
between Post, PostComment and my array post or furthermore his own method of recuperation `_POST`.
you can see from the error above that it's based on hesitation between Post and post ,if you are using a latest version of Symfony, try to scan you whole project and change the names of your attributes or classes, believe it or not it creates some difficulties for the IDE when your project gets bigger

and here is what made the error gone:

- old

```
/**
* @var integer
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="post")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_post",referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $idPost;
```

- new

```
/**
* @var integer
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_post",referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $idPost;
```

I was not giving the appropriate name of my Entity, so when I do any operation based on foreign keys, the IDE won't find any Entity of reference

if you are using and old version of Symfony, you have to add a line of code in some file's configuration
you can have a better explanation here:

[Symfony2 error : Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268366/symfony2-error-case-mismatch-between-loaded-and-declared-class-names)

Answer (score 1):

Once have look on the folder name of your userbundle file.
Since, you have mentioned UserBunlde in your namespace **(namespace MyApp\UserBundle\Entity;) then,
Your folder name must be **UserBundle** too.
If you have named as userBundle so that such error occurs.